# One URL to round robin access variable login.html

Tags: javascript, html

I need users to be able to access our program with one of ten user names/passwords without the user needing to know any of those. To fix this I have created multiple `*.html` and corresponding Javascript files to auto-populate user names/passwords. (`xxxx.login.html`, `xxxx.login1.html`, `xxxx.login2.html`, etc. - these point to `login.js`, `login1.js`, `login2.js` respectively) Can these be accessed “round robin” style from a link on another website?

My goal is for the customer to go to a registration page, and click the access link, at which point one of the ten auto-logins will be accessed. The customer shouldn’t notice anything, other than a different user name at the top of the screen. (Each `loginx.html` is already verified and working to log the user in.)

Comment: Huh? You want users to access the system with 1/10 username/password combos without knowing any of them?! What kind of login system is that? DON'T PREFILL LOGIN INFO! What if someone stumbles upon the URL, or shares it?

Comment: For almost all situations that is a horrible idea! There probably are a couple time that could be fine for but it makes the security consciousness in me quiver.

Comment: @BenM Maybe its a demo system, and this is desired?

Comment: Then if it's a demo, have one account and tell all users what it is?!

Comment: "Come on down and spin the wheel of logins! **Win *every* time!!**" This is a serious security breach waiting to happen. For the love of your data's security PLEASE consider re-structuring your processes.

Comment: "One URL to rule them all, One URL to find them; One URL to bring them all and log them in the program."

Answer (score 0):

Without questioning your motives, there are two ways of doing it that come to my mind:

1- PHP Header Redirect - Where you send all the users to one page which redirects them to a random one.

2- A link with PHP that randomly changes the page number in the link each time someone visits the page.

```
<a href="xxxx.login<?php echo(rand(1,9));?>.html">Link</a>
```

This will give you a random number between 1 and 9 on an Apache/PHP server:

```
<?php echo(rand(1,9));?>
```

And the web page source will apear as:

```
<a href="xxxx.login7.html">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're willing to turn your HTML files into PHP files, and also assuming that you want to show these pages sequentially (round-robin) on a per user basis.  Something like this should work as long as these pages are served from the same domain.

This can go at the top of your first login page, them point the link to this file which will read the cookie if it exists, and redirect tot he next page in the array. Otherwise, it will stay on the first login form and set a cookie for the next visit.

```
<?php

$pages = array('/xxxx.login.php', '/xxxx.login1.php', '/xxxx.login2.php');

if(array_search($_COOKIE['lastPage'], $pages) < count($pages) - 1){
    header('Location: '.$pages[array_search($_COOKIE['lastPage'], $pages) + 1]);
}

setcookie('lastPage', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 60*60*24); // Set the expiration of the cookie in place of 60*60*24

    ?>

// Your first login page html
```

Then this at the top of your other login pages

```
<?php

setcookie('lastPage', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 60*60*24);
```